# jquery funcion calcular porcentaje dinamico

Tags: jquery

Este es el problema:

Tengo `#producto_1`, `#producto_2` y `#producto_3`, cada uno tiene `inputs` a rellenar de forma automática.

La forma de calcular el neto es: `bruto*merma/100`, como tengo para agregar mas `#producto_n` quiero que funcione mas de 1 o 2 veces llamando la función desde: `onchange="calculaNeto()`

Si hay un metodo mejor, no estoy cerrado al progreso, gracias de antemano

```js
function calculaNeto() {
         var bruto = $(this).parent().next().find("input").val();
         var mermas = $(this).val();
         var merma = 100-mermas;
         var neto = bruto*(merma/100);
         $(this).parents().next().find("input").val(neto);
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="producto_1" class="row">
<div id="colusku_1" class="col-sm-2">
             <label>Peso bruto</label>
             <input type='number' class='form-control' name='bruto1' id='colsku_1'  required>
           </div>
           <div id="colucant_1" class="col-sm-1">
             <label>% Merma</label>
             <input type='number' class='form-control' name='perdida1' id='colcant_1' onchange="calculaNeto()" required>
           </div>
           <div id="colucost_1" class="col-sm-2">
             <label>Peso Neto <sup>auto</sup> </label>
             <input type='number' class='form-control' name='neto1' id='colcost_1' required>
           </div>
      </div>
<div id="producto_2" class="row">
<div id="colusku_2" class="col-sm-2">
             <label>Peso bruto</label>
             <input type='number' class='form-control' name='bruto1' id='colsku_2'  required>
           </div>
           <div id="colucant_2" class="col-sm-1">
             <label>% Merma</label>
             <input type='number' class='form-control' name='perdida2' id='colcant_2' onchange="calculaNeto()" required>
           </div>
           <div id="colucost_2" class="col-sm-2">
             <label>Peso Neto <sup>auto</sup> </label>
             <input type='number' class='form-control' name='neto2' id='colcost_2' required>
           </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te recomiendo que en lugar de trabajarlo por medio de `onclick` ya que no es para nada buena práctica, en cambio, podrías asignar una clase al `div` padre, y a cada uno de los tres `input` que manejas. De esa manera, usando `jQuery` es sencillo llegar a lo que pretendes.

```js
//Ejecuto si cambia cualquier elemento con clase pesoBruto o merma
jQuery('.pesoBruto , .merma').on('change',function()
{

      //Obtengo el valor bruto
      var bruto = $(this).closest('.producto').children('.pesoBruto').val();
      //Obtengo %Merma
      var merma = $(this).closest('.producto').children('.merma').val();

      //En caso de que alguno de los dos este en blanco, el neto estará en blanco.
      if(bruto.length==0 || merma.length==0){
        $(this).closest('.producto').children('.neto').val("");
        return;
      }

      //Realizo el cálculo
      var neto = bruto*merma/100;

      //Lo muestro en el div neto
      $(this).closest('.producto').children('.neto').val(neto);

});
```

```css
input
{
width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="producto">
  <label>Peso bruto</label>
  <input type="number" class="pesoBruto">
  <label>%Merma</label>
  <input type="number" class="merma">
  <label>Peso neto</label>
  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="neto">
</div>

<hr>

<div class="producto">
    <label>Peso bruto</label>
    <input type="number" class="pesoBruto">
    <label>%Merma</label>
    <input type="number" class="merma">
    <label>Peso neto</label>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="neto">
</div>
```

Fijate, que el código no es muy complejo, para obtener los valores tanto de `bruto` como de `merma` uso la función `closest(selector)` para hallar el `div` con clase `.producto` más cercano, luego con `children(selector)` ubico el `input` que necesito para realizar el cálculo

Espero que quede claro!

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio mucho, de paso apprendí algo, muchas gracias.